# Determining a phone's SMS / MMS carrier in the US

Tags: php, sms

Okay so I know how to send out SMS's / MMS's via a phone with a provided carrier (via matching the carrier's email.. i.e. Verizon = @vtext.com).

Now, I also know that I can use services like Twilio, but I think it doesn't make sense to pay for something you can achieve programmatically. Same goes for Cloudvox, it's free but I noticed it's not accurate.

So here's what I thought of: What if we took the number, switched it amongst the various popular carriers (via SMTP mail check) and return the confirmed carrier.

I attempted to test with vtext.com, but it didn't work.. I'm assuming they don't accept mailbox check's via SMTP?

Comment: Why don't you try to use cURL to get the data from those websites instead of using SMTP?

Comment: I could do that, but what do I cURL against?  As mentioned above, cloudvox has cURL capability via JSON (so as Twilio) but they have a cost and or not accurate.

Comment: Relying on a returned SMTP error from a mailhost is also going to very sketchy. Maybe you can sniff a provider based on the phone blocks sold by carrier, but even that will be somewhat sketchy, since you can transfer numbers nowadays.

Comment: I used to be with an SMS aggregator that was going the email route for a couple carriers. It all worked well until Verizon blacklisted *all* of our servers one day. Poof. Our customers were cut off and we didn't notice for hours..  I joined Twilio because it's cheap & easy and just works. Is it free? Nope, but it's risk/reward at that point.

Comment: I'm assuming that Twilio leases out numbers and sends text out directly from those numbers, right?  That way, the carrier it self does the routing (instead of via email).

Comment: Twilio is definitely great though.. Is there a limit for email routing?

Comment: @MichaelMikhjian - There isn't a limit for email routing.. but there's no guarantee either.

Comment: Ahhh okay.  I'm going to have to do research on this.. There must be a way to determine a numbers carrier by testing.

Comment: Relying on email gateways for messaging can, like with @CaseySoftware 's experience be unreliable. SMS Gateways get the reliability by having direct connections. To find which network a mobile number is on, this data is available but not surprisingly businesses realise there's money to be made from this and so usually charge for access to it (services like gsm.org's Pathfinder). Number ranges are assigned to carriers like IP addresses are but in some countries numbers can be ported to other networks. See numberingplans.com for a basic view on number ranges worldwide.

Comment: Cloudvox provides the carrier information with their API for free.  However, I noticed that the information they hold is not always latest, e.g. I checked up on one of my numbers and it had my old carrier listed.

Comment: Does anyone know or seen an article on how Twilio works exactly?  Did they buy a big bulk of numbers? Do those numbers port into servers, where they make calls and text out? (Or maybe it's all virtual, but who's their service provider?)

Comment: It will be all virtual. I work an SMS Gateway. The numbers that you can be assigned when you use one of these services have been bought and are hosted by a particular carrier. They'll then have a direct connection to that carrier to ensure that inbound SMS are routed to them instead of to a handset. It's virtual in the sense that there is no SIM card / GSM modem receiving messages. The carrier simply routes the SMS down the direct connection in the same way they would pass a message onto another network if it wasn't for one of their subscribers.

Comment: Makes sense jbjon; so in that case, if one were to want that access with the SMS and setup a complete custom solution.. where would one look and ask for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment thread to your question there is no reliable, free method of determining what mobile network a phone number is currently on. 
MSISDNs get allocated to telephony networks to begin with but then customers can be free to move their numbers between carriers these days. The free information you can get from services like numberingplans.com then becomes invalid as the initial network allocation no longer applies.

Whilst the US seems to make use of the mobile networks providing a free method of sending SMS via an email address, this is not normally the case for networks around the world.

Mobile networks themselves are subscribed to up to date lists. If an SMS isn't destined for a number they know they host, they will consult the list to determine what network interconnect to send it out to. This is how your mobile handset is able to SMS users on other networks.

You can still use email to send SMS using SMS Gateway services like Esendex or Clickatel. They would then determine the best route to send the messages (provided the SMS Gateway themselves have more than one route out which some of the low cost ones don't) and as they have direct interconnects to the mobile networks its then routed in a similar manner to if you'd sent the message yourself using a handset. Twilio's service involves using their API rather than email to send messages. Esendex, Clickatel and the like will also provide API access.

So if your message is important enough for you to want to ensure that it gets to the right place, then the best way is to shop around for a reliable, professional SMS Gateway that will assist you in getting your message delivered without you having to have that headache.

(Disclaimer: I work for Esendex but provide this answer as a general approach to how sending SMS using an SMS Gateway solves your problem as the alternative solution of using email addresses to send to US networks reliably requires paid access to number location databases to make sure your message got through.)